# Validate unique entry on edit/update

Tags: php, mysql, validation, edit

I'm trying to validate a unique entry when editing/updating a record.
I am validating by searching the database, if the entry is not found then proceed else print an error message. If an entry  (I am using this same process when adding new records)

My validation code is:

```
if (!empty($_POST['ip_add'])) {
    if (filter_var($_POST['ip_add'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4) === false) {
        $errors[] = $_POST['ip_add'] . ' is not a valid IPv4';
    } else {
        $ip = $_POST['ip_add'];
        //check if ip is unique
        $qip = 'select INET_NTOA(ip_add) AS ip_add from equipment where ip_add = INET_ATON(:ip)';
        $database->query($qip);

        $database->bind(':ip', $ip);
        $rs = $database->resultset();
        //execute our query
        $database->execute();
        if ($rs != null) {
            $errors[] = $_POST['ip_add'] . ' is not unique';
        } else {
            $ip_add = $_POST['ip_add'];
        }
    }
} else {
    $errors[] = "Please enter a valid IP address";
}
```

if there are no errors update database:

```
$query = "
  UPDATE equipment
  SET site_code = :site_code,
    site_id = :site_id,
    system_name = :system_name,
    ip_add = INET_ATON(:ip_add),
    mcast =  INET_ATON(:mcast),
    sys_loc = :sys_loc,
    systype = :systype,
    itamname = :itamname,
    dimetis = :dimetis,
    DNS = :DNS
  WHERE id = :id
";

//prepare query for excecution
$database->query($query);
//bind the parameters
$database->bind(':site_code', $site_code);
$database->bind(':site_id', $site_id);
$database->bind(':system_name', $system_name);
$database->bind(':ip_add', $ip_add);
$database->bind(':mcast', $multicast);
$database->bind(':sys_loc', $sys_loc);
$database->bind(':systype', $systype);
$database->bind(':itamname', $itamname);
$database->bind(':dimetis', $_POST['dimetis']);
$database->bind(':DNS', $_POST['DNS']);
$database->bind(':id', $_POST['id']);

// Execute the query
$database->execute();
echo "Record was updated.";
}
}
```

I was thinking I could search on all records execpt current record that I am currently editing.
How would I do this?
Is there a better way for checking if IP addrss is unique when editing a record?

Comment: So what is it you're asking here?

Comment: I figured this out as I was writing the question this by excluding current record from update. I left it as it may be useful to someone else. I guess I'm asking if this is the best way or is there another/better way?

Comment: A comment, not on your question, but what to do with it. You can answer your own question. Take out the answer from your question above and paste it into an answer. That way it's clear that the question has been answered, rather than leaving it unclear what you want.

Comment: Tks Mike - have done as suggested. Hopefully of use to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work be excluding current record from search:

```
$qip = '
  SELECT
    INET_NTOA(ip_add) AS ip_add
  FROM equipment
  WHERE
    ip_add = INET_ATON(:ip)
    AND id != :id
';
$database->query($qip);

$database->bind(':ip', $ip);
$database->bind(':id', $id);
```